# Data Studio calculated field: how to extract domain from url

Tags: regex, looker-studio, re2

I have a Data Studio report with Google Sheet document as data source. In the data source i have a column with urls - to create a good looking report i need domains. Until now i extract domains from urls directly in the Google Sheet - i use the following formula:

```
=IFNA(trim(REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(BT2,"https?://",""),"^(w{3}\.)?","")&"/","([^/?]+)")),"")
```

and i get from `https://www.example.com/pag.html` → `example.com`, which is expected output.

But how should look a regular expression, which does the same, in Data Studio?

I tried two expression variant,s but achieved an expected output only in parts:

- `REGEXP_EXTRACT(URL, "//(.*?)/")` - but with this expression the subdomain, like www, remains unfiltered.
- `REGEXP_EXTRACT(URL, '^[^.]+.([^.]+)')` - extracts only the domain name - without subdomain, but without TLD too.

How can i enhance the last expression to filter any subdomain, not only www, out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adapted the respective Google Sheets formula in the question to Google Data Studio, using the [Calculated Field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685):

```
TRIM(REGEXP_EXTRACT(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(URL, "https?://", ""), R"^(w{3}\.)?", ""), "([^/?]+)"))
```

[Editable Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/ac7207ee-8a38-4757-8a0d-952b7e3df065) (Embedded [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AEr8JM_TjNQB6DBF7FTObKSCqYQTke9MH7k0Jc_Aj68/edit?usp=sharing) Data Source) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]